# Google Maps V3 is not showing in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have this contact us form with a a google map V3 which is not showing

http://www.ehlersattorneys.co.za/contact-us

I added the new google api key and enabled google maps etc... I can't understand why but it doesn't show the map, can someone help me with this please?

The strange thing is that it's working fine in Safari.. but not in other browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, your problem is caused by the /* MAX IMAGE WIDTH */ style definition

```
 /* MAX IMAGE WIDTH */

 img {
    height:auto !important;
    max-width:100% !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box !important;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
 }
```

The

```
    max-width:100% !important;
```

causes the problem. If you remove the line or at least the `!important` clause, the map will work. (I have tried with Chrome)